# React.JS App MODULE_NOT_FOUND error on 'npm start'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

After creating a react application, when I run the command `npm start` I have the following error:

```bash
PS G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client> npm start

> client@0.1.0 start G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parse.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-10T19_26_53_509Z-debug.log
```

And here's the full log file :

```bash
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v13.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prestart: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\gabri\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files\WorldPainter;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\6.1937.0.23352\bin\Firefox_Extension\{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\6.1937.0.23352\ucrt;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\6.1937.0.23352\bin\Qt;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\6.1937.0.23352\bin\Ssl;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\workspace\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: CWD: G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd G:\workspace\WEB\gab-web\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v13.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading your npm to v14.5 or later, also remove `react-create-app` globally:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then try recreating your project:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

It's a known issue, credits: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9273#issuecomment-654182223

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue during installing node js on my system so i have tried to change the directory ( File installation ) for node js & it works...

Changed Destination:-

C:\JAVA\

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face such issues the solution related to your file path not found is because when you start a project and you stop and when you want to go back to such project . many developers tend to forget they need to change directory into the app they created . for example let me say the name of the app was clean-app and you have cleared your server out and to go back to such projects prior to using npm start , you need to cd into the directory or else it will keep stating "[] module not found" and this happen to me a few times before I remembered I had to Cd into the file,  so to solve such issues , you cd into the the name of the app and then you type npm start and when you clone someones project and maybe the persons main file and and start file are different , try checking the main file and and changing the name of the main file to that of the start file in the package.json. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear dependencies and try again:

```
npm cache clear --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120799/2415632

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I simply deleted `tsconfig.js` file and restarted `npm start`. Problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).