# React js code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', not able to run reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, npm-install, npm-start

I'm facing this issue after run `npm i` Actually this react app share by someone so right now i'm trying to run it in my PC. First of all i run `npm i` to install npm but this is giving error as given below:-

I just want to run this code how can i do this what wrong with it?

```js
error
```

Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843293/ng-serve-cannot-find-module-tapable

Comment: still get same error.

Answer (score 2):

Clear everything and try again:

```
npm cache clear --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: giving error when i run `rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
PS E:\Project\test\ClientApp> rm -rf node_modules
Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -rf node_modules
+    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Try  `rm -r -fo node_modules ` instead of line 2

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command :

`npm install --save tapable`

then run your project.

Comment: done this but still getting same error...

Comment: can you share your package.json dependencies json ?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  }

Comment: Not a `devDependencies` Sir, need to see `dependencies` .

Comment: I added dependencies in snippet please check now

Comment: Checked, Still I can't found `tapable` package in your dependencies, Please make sure it must be in that list when you run your project.

Comment: how can i add this?

Comment: I changed my answer try that command

Comment: still not working...